# android: XML switches buttons but not the functionality

Tags: android, xml, genymotion

I get a weird behaviour and i"m not sure i"m supposed to.

i have 4 button. 2 are "True" and "False". and another two are "Prev" and "Next".:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button android:id="@+id/prev_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/prev_question_button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp" />        
            <Button android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next_question_button"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp" />
      </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/true_button" />
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/false_button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to switch the buttons so the "next" and "prev" will be underneath the true false.
When i move the first  linear layout block, after the second one. i get the buttons in the right order BUT the prev and next buttons behave as True/False buttons and the True/False buttons behave as the next/Prev (the functionality stayed the same order)

What am i doing wrong?
(Im new to XML and android)

**Edit:**
I'm not switching id's. So i cant tell why it behaves that way.

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private Button mPrevButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;
    private TrueFalse mQuestionBank[] = new TrueFalse[] {
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_aftrica, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, false) };
    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    private void updateQuestion() {
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }

    private void checkAnswer(boolean useRressedTrue) {
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();
        System.out.println("check");
        int textID;
        if (useRressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
            textID = R.string.correct_toast;
        } else {
            textID = R.string.incorrect_toast;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, textID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // System.out.println("check dis");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view); 
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);

        mQuestionTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();

            }
        });

        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        checkAnswer(true);

                    }

                });
        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                checkAnswer(false);

            }

        });
        mPrevButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
        mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });
        mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });
        updateQuestion();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a RelativeLAyout. you can place your buttons relative to one another

Comment: what do you mean by "switches buttons but not functionality"??

Comment: I mean that when i press the "next" button what i get is the "True" button

Comment: post your activity code this has nothing to do with the layout. Button click listener will work the way the are meant to work. If you switch ids when referencing then you may end in like what you mention. I want to be sure. so post the java code

Comment: Edited. Im not switching id's. thats why it is wierd

Comment: Looks fine i don't think the functionality will change. try clean and build

Answer (score 1):

Using `RelativeLayout` is better although it can be achieved with `LinearLayout` also

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

```
I want to switch the buttons so the "next" and "prev" will be underneath the true false
```

The views can be re-arranged in xml. I do not know what you are talking about functionality.

You need to reference the right id in your Activity. I guess you are switching id also.

Edit:

After looking at the edited post i do not see anything wrong. I suggest you clean and build your project or try uninstall and re-install.

Comment: **Edited**
The code if the activity, as you see. no change with the id's.

Comment: @YevgeniTarler there is no problem. i do not get what functionality you are talking about. or try uninstall and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the R.java file, it Recreated me another one, and now it works. No clue why.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you clean and build your project also it should work coz R.java will be regenerated

Comment: it builds automatically after each clean. is there a better way?

Comment: Normally this should not happen. Suppose you add a new resource with a id an entry is made in R.java immediately. So its updated. In your case it din't. And clean and build should fix it.